# Autolayout treats iOS7 screen differently from iOS 6

Tags: autolayout, ios7, xcode5

**Scenario:** iOS6 & iOS7 (4"inch) sharing the same XIB.

**Problem:** Both display different layout, albeit sharing the same constraints, etc.

The following images are snapshots of simulated iOS6 & iOS7 version 
of the SAME Layout/Constraints:

[image: iOS6 Layout]

Notice the different layout patter for the fields & button:

[image: iOS7 Layout]

**Question:** How can I get iOS6 & iOS7 layouts in sync; i.e., behave the same?

Here's a snapshot of all the constraints:

[image]

Comment: This question brushed into NDA based SDKs. The OP is not allowed to discuss iOS 7.

Comment: Applications/OS being discussed are under NDA. You should ask this question in devforums.apple.com –

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I had two conflicting vertical spaces (that *wasn't flagged by Xcode 5*).
Near the bottom of the complaint list (see above), there are two 'Vertical Space' constants for the 'Please wait while we...' label: (92) vs (26).

By removing one of them (26), the (iOS 6) layout has  adjusted to be in sync with its iOS 7 counterpart.

Still odd...
... why didn't BOTH environments behave the same in the first place?